# Как дать права на /var/www/* для poedit?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня постоянно возникает путаница с правами доступа к файлам и папкам :(. И если дать права на папку для пользователя ещё понятно (`sudo chmod -R 777 /dir.../`). Но как поступить в данной ситуации:

Установил poedit для локализации темы для WP, локально проект находится `/var/www/`. При попытке открыть файл локализации через poedit вижу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Права на `/var/`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Права на `/var/www/`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приложение ставил `sudo snap install poedit`.

Подскажите, что необходимо сделать, для того чтобы poedit видел файлы в директории `/var/www/`? Просто очень не хочется таскать файл из папка проекта в `/home/$USER` и обратно...

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777` — почему? ну почему, если дверь заперта, то первым делом берут в руки кувалду вместо ключа? честное слово, лучше бы вы эту кувалду применили к тому, кто вам её когда-то злобно присоветовал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перепробовав все возможные варианты, нашел решение. Удалил snap (`snap remove poedit`) и установил poedit через apt (`sudo apt install poedit`).

Теперь доступ к директориям и файлам на которых владельцем установлен пользователь(`$USER` ) есть.

Comment: Со snap там не всё так просто. Он запускает все приложения в песочнице, поэтому та среда, в которой его приложения запускаются, просто не дает им интерфейса, через который они могли бы получить доступ к некоторым каталогам. Где есть возможность, лучше снапом не пользоваться :)